# vba error number 9 subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, subscript

I'm trying to make a Excel 2007 vba code to select a sheet using userform. While testing, I'm getting **'Subscript out of range'** Error if I input a sheetname which is not there in workbook. my code is below.

```
Private Sub Okbtn_Click()
sheetname = Me.ComboBox1.Value
If sheetname = "" Then
    Unload Me
    MsgBox "Sheet Name not enetered", vbExclamation, "Hey!"
    Exit Sub
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Activate 'Error points here!!

On Error GoTo errmsg
'If Error.Value = 9 Then GoTo errmsg
Unload Me
MsgBox "Now you are in sheet: " & sheetname & "!", vbInformation, "Sheet Changed"

errmsg:
MsgBox ("Sheet name not found in " & ThisWorkbook.Name & " !")
End Sub
```

The error is in `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Activate` . I tried to put some error handing tricks before and after the problem line, but Im getting the same error-9.

Im very new to coding. I think I explained the problem correctly. I want to avoid the error from popping up, but should show a customized message instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move your `On Error GoTo errmsg` code line *above* the worksheet activation, the error should be handled by the error trap routine. You just need to exit the sub before reaching the same routine if successful.

```
    On Error GoTo errmsg
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Activate 'Error points here!!

    Unload Me
    MsgBox "Now you are in sheet: " & sheetname & "!", vbInformation, "Sheet Changed"
    Exit Sub

    errmsg:
    MsgBox ("Sheet name not found in " & ThisWorkbook.Name & " !")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the error handler before executing the instruction that might cause an error.  Something like this

```
Private Sub Okbtn_Click()
sheetname = Me.ComboBox1.Value
If sheetname = "" Then
    Unload Me
    MsgBox "Sheet Name not enetered", vbExclamation, "Hey!"
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo errmsg

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Activate 'Error points here!!


'If Error.Value = 9 Then GoTo errmsg
Unload Me
MsgBox "Now you are in sheet: " & sheetname & "!", vbInformation, "Sheet Changed"

Exit Sub ' Avoid executing handler code when ther is no error
errmsg:
MsgBox ("Sheet name not found in " & ThisWorkbook.Name & " !")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

put `On Error GoTo errmsg` above `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Activate`

```
'''''
On Error GoTo errmsg
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Activate
'''''
```

error handling always must be before the line where you can receive the error

Answer (score 0):

It would be clearer if you error handling was wrapped around a single line  testing if the worksheet existed

As an example your current code will flag any error - such as the sheet being hidden - as the sheet not existing.

```
Private Sub Okbtn_Click()
Dim strSht As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

strSht = Me.ComboBox1.Value

If Len(strSht) = 0 Then
    Unload Me
    MsgBox "Sheet Name not entered", vbExclamation, "Hey!"
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error Resume Next
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSht)
On Error GoTo 0


If Not ws Is Nothing Then
     If ws.Visible Then
        Application.Goto ws.[a1]
        MsgBox "Now you are in sheet: " & strSht & "!", vbInformation, "Sheet Changed"
    Else
        MsgBox ("Sheet exists but is hidden")
    End If
Else
    MsgBox ("Sheet name not found in " & ThisWorkbook.Name & " !")
End If

End Sub
```